# CSR - Show list items horizontally

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering, layouts

Am new to CSR. We have a requirement wherein we have to display list items horizontally. I looked for couple of links on internet by found them too complicated and bit confusing. Our guess is by simple overrride of a layout function things should work. 
I will be if great help to us and others if a sample code is shared.

Thank you.